# package.xml "provides"

Tags: ros, package.xml, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In version 2 of package.xml format, the "conflict" and "replace" tags are now available (yay).  But what about the sibling "provides"?   https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html#s-virtual

Use case:

I make two packages, one that interacts with actual hardware (my_driver_real) and one that interacts with simulated hardware (my_driver_fake).  Both implement the same interface, so dependent packages don't know or care which is used.   But both can't be available on the same system, because they have the same file names (so they're interchangeable).

Ideally, I'd set both packages to "provide" an "interface name" (my_driver), as well as both conflict and replace.  Then, a user can apt-get install my_driver_real, and if my_driver_fake is already installed it will be replaced.  And other packages would simply (debian) depend on the "interface name", and as long as one of them was installed, all would be well.

Thoughts?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202852/package.xml-%22provides%22/) by [dustingooding](https://answers.ros.org/users/3314/dustingooding/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2015-02-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We explicitly did not support this as we do not support optional dependencies, but we have some reasons for not supporting it.

Consider this: You have package `foo` which depends on `bar` OR `bar_faux` using a provides "Bar" kind of thing. Then you run `rosinstall_generator foo --deps`, what does `rosinstall_generator` generate as the dependencies for `foo`? Does it include `bar` or `bar_faux` or both? Presumably `bar` and `bar_faux` cannot be installed at the same time, if they can, why not depend on both?

Another similar scenario: You have not released any of the aforementioned packages. You have checked out `foo` and `bar_faux` into a `src` folder. Then you ask `rosdep` to install dependencies for `foo`, does it install `bar`?

These are both example of how this feature would complicate the existing tools, but then there is packaging. This is where it is really problematic, consider: `bar` and `bar_faux` provide `Bar`, and `foo` depends on `Bar`, so when you are generating the `.deb` for `foo` you can handle that since `apt` has the mechanism to support it, but what about when you are packaging for Homebrew or Gentoo or anything which doesn't have that mechanism? You now have to look at all release packages and see which ones provide `Bar` and add them as explicit dependencies.

At that point you have to decide which one of the packages providing `Bar` should be directly depended on. The only way to do this, that I can imagine, is that one of the packages which "provides" `Bar` declares itself as the default. But then how do you handle if multiple packages do this or if no packages do this. The later could be because the default one has not been released yet.

By comparison `replaces` and `conflicts` can relatively safely be ignored by package managers which do not support it and do not complicate the toolchain significantly.

---

For the scenario you described, ROS is specifically designed for this case, but you should use multiple packages and a message interface to provide the abstraction not a "provides" mechanism.

You can have a package `my_driver_msgs`, which contains the interface, then a package which uses `my_driver_msgs` like `my_driver_consumer` which can either have a direct dependency on `my_driver` or `my_driver_fake` or both. Then your launch files will need to run one or the other. It's more of a composition, you might even have another package like `test_my_driver_consumer` which depends on `my_driver_fake` and `gazebo` or something which has a launch file which launches `my_driver_consumer` and `my_driver_fake` together.

Essentially we typically address this OR dependency in CMake or launch files.

---

With all of that being said, you can modify your `debian/control` file in the release process to do what ever you want. We're just not willing to support that mechanism across all of our tools and support platforms (current and future).

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dustingooding](https://answers.ros.org/users/3314/dustingooding/) on 2015-06-24**:
Good rationale.  Thanks @William!